# Calculate the amount of different combinations with rules

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I am wondering how to calculate the amount of possible combinations for this scenario:
Say a party bag contains 6 different sweets, and that these are a random selection from 8 different types of sweets. However, no more than 2 of the same type of sweet can be put into the party bag and no fewer than 4 different types of sweet can be put into the party bag. How many different party bags are possible, and how would I calculate it?

Answer (score 3):

The numbers are quite small, so we need not be very clever in our counting. Divide into **cases**.

(a) Maybe the bag has $6$ different types of sweet. These can be chosen in $\binom{8}{6}=28$ ways.

(b) Maybe the bag has $5$ different types of sweet. Then we will have $2$ of one type, and $1$ each of $4$ other types. The type we have $2$ of can be chosen in $\binom{8}{1}$ ways. For each such choice, there are $\binom{7}{4}$ ways to select the other types, for a total of $\binom{8}{1}\binom{7}{4}=280$.

(c) Maybe the bag has $4$ different types only. Since $3$ of one type is not allowed, we must have $2$ each of $2$ types, and $1$ each of $2$ other types.

The two types we have $2$ each of can be chosen in $\binom{8}{2}$ ways, and then the $2$ singletons in $\binom{6}{2}$ ways, for a total of $\binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{2}=420$.

Add up the $3$ numbers we have obtained.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put "no fewer than 4 different types of sweet can be put in". This means we cannot have the numbers obtained in (c), I do not think, because we cannot have 3 of one type. We can only have 2 of one type and no less than 4 of different types. Basically, we can have them all different or we can have two of one type with the 4 other ones different, in a bag. So I think that (a) and (b) from you are still valid. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Next, I will use the two numbers that you gave me as n and r respectively, and use the formula n! / (r!(n-r)!)

Comment: I have made the change, now there is only one entry under (c), marginally simpler. Note that $2$ of sweet A, $2$ of sweet C, and $1$ each of sweets D and F is allowed by the wording. So *some* of (c) survives and has to be counted.

Comment: I do not agree with your interpretation of the wording. You will need to use also $\binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{2}$.

Comment: Oh right, yes. However, will \binom{8}{1} not have to be multiplied by two, seeing as we are getting it twice?

Comment: If you are referring to Case (c), it is $\binom{8}{2}$, not $\binom{8}{1}$.  And it is unfortunately quite easy to think that part should be $\binom{8}{1}\binom{7}{1}$. (That is a very common error.) However, that would overcount by a factor $2$: Two sweets of type A and $2$ of type D is the same as $2$ of type $D$ and $2$ of type A.